# how do i make this while loop into a method?

Tags: python, sockets

Instead of returning the values in an infinite loop from the server, I want to make a method, example getPositions() which returns the specific position that I want to while the connection server is still running. How do I do it?

```
import socket
import os,sys
import time

HOST = '59.191.193.59'
PORT = 5555

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((HOST,PORT))

screen_width = 0
screen_height = 0
while True:

    client_socket.send("loc\n")
    data = client_socket.recv(8192)
    coordinates = data.split()

    if(not(coordinates[-1] == "eom" and coordinates[0] == "start")):
        continue

    if (screen_width != int(coordinates[2])):
        screen_width = int(coordinates[2])
        screen_height = int(coordinates[3])


    print int(coordinates[8])
    print int(coordinates[9])
    print int(coordinates[12])
    print int(coordinates[13])
```

[image]

Comment: Your `if` condition will not work properly. The stuff after `continue` will never execute.

Comment: @Edward Edit your post by clicking on the link `Edit` right under the keywords of your post. I already did it :)

Comment: What about `client_socket = socket.create_connection((HOST,PORT))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty straight-forward:

```
import socket
import os,sys
import time
from threading import Thread

HOST = '59.191.193.59'
PORT = 5555

COORDINATES = []

def connect():   
    globals()['client_socket'] = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((HOST,PORT))

def update_coordinates():
    connect()
    screen_width = 0
    screen_height = 0
    while True:
        try:
            client_socket.send("loc\n")
            data = client_socket.recv(8192)
        exept:
            connect();
            continue;

        globals()['COORDINATES'] = data.split()

        if(not(COORDINATES[-1] == "eom" and COORDINATES[0] == "start")):
            continue

            if (screen_width != int(COORDINATES[2])):
                screen_width = int(COORDINATES[2])
                screen_height = int(COORDINATES[3])            

Thread(target=update_coordinates).start()

// Run your controlling app here. COORDINATES will be available in the global scope and will be updated constantly
```

EDIT: Created Method inside the get_coordinates function to re-establish socket connection in the event of a failure.

Comment: *Was there anything else you wanted to do?* Yes, probably the *make a method, example getPositions() which returns the specific position* part. But I admit the question is not very clear...

Comment: @Mr.Steak because I am returning the values form the server which is connected to a camera and object detection using open cv. i am just scared that if it might get disconnected from the server if I place the the code i have now in a method

Comment: @David Morton like i mention earlier i am just scared that it will be disconnected from the server because i am using live data from the server (:

Comment: @Edward: There's really no reason why moving the socket.send and socket.recv methods into a function would increase the likelihood of the connection being dropped. That being said, I've modified the example code so that it will automatically try to reconnect in the event that the connection is dropped.

Comment: @DavidMorton yeah true, the point of me actually asking this is to have a method so i could use it somethere else in another loop within the program because i am using this update coordinates method to update the position of a robot in my robot control loop so yeahh

Comment: @Edward Have you thought much about how you want to run the control loop concurrently with the loop that updates coordinate? It may be a use caes for a separate thread where coordinates are available to the control thread as well. Would you like for me to mock that up?

Comment: @DavidMorton it's a soccer playing robot, so i guess i'll use the update coordinate whenever the robot losses the ball, so i guess pretty much all the time? yeah sure why not? (:

Comment: @DavidMorton and dont bother about the print int(coordinates[8]) i was gonna change it to returning the values instead so i could use it for another method like for example move_to(values...)

Comment: @Edward Yeah...I took out the print statements. But COORDINATES is now available in the global scope, so you can access it from any other methods (the values will be continually updated. The get_coordinates thread will run as a daemon and won't block any of the other parts of the application. I also moved the connect() method outside of get_coordinates. You shouldn't need to call it because get coordinates will automatically try to reestablish the connection if for any reason it is dropped. Good luck!

Comment: @DavidMorton alright (: thanks, i'll try it out and let you know if it works and one more thing i could call the get_coordinates method too if i want too right?

Comment: @DavidMorton heyy its not wokring when i type print COORDINATES[:] under the thread line is prints nothing

Comment: @Edward There's a syntax error "exept" should be "except". Can you also just verify that the connect() method works and then that the following two statements update coordinates:             client_socket.send("loc\n")
            data = client_socket.recv(8192)

Comment: @DavidMorton yeah i changed that and it works. i just want to know how do i access the COORDINATES because when i tried it keep giving me list index out of range

Comment: @DavidMorton have edited the answer above with screenshot of the error produced

Comment: @Edward The thread that you've initialized and kicked off probably hasn't gotten the response back by the time that your program gets to the COORDINATES[8] statement. Try adding the line update_coordinates() right above the statement initializing and starting the Thread.

Comment: @DavidMorton if i want to add a last_coordinates = [] which containst the previous values of COORDINATES list. so i could compare both values where should i place this last_coordinates list and how should i instantiate it

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
import os,sys
import time

HOST = '59.191.193.59'
PORT = 5555

# don't restrict yourself to IPv4 without any need:
client_socket = socket.create_connection((HOST,PORT))

def update_coordinates(client_socket):
    client_socket.send("loc\n")
    data = client_socket.recv(8192)
    coordinates = data.split()

    if(not(coordinates[-1] == "eom" and coordinates[0] == "start")):
        return None # or so

    return [int(i) for i in coordinates[1:-1]]

screen_width = 0
screen_height = 0

while True:
    coord = update_coordinates(screen_width)
    if coord is None: continue
    # ! indexes have changed...
    if (screen_width != coord[1]):
        screen_width = coord[1]
        screen_height = coord[2]
    print coordinates[7]
    print coordinates[8]
    print coordinates[11]
    print coordinates[12]
```

I'm not sure if I got the question right, though...

Comment: if your solution returns the data from the server and it allows me to use the update coordinate method whenever i need to then it should be right and the data is returned in a string like this ['start', 'inch', '640', '480', '0', '0', '640', '480', '488', '290', '15', 'teset1', '336', '184', '37', 'eom']

Comment: if your solution returns the data from the server and it allows me to use the update coordinate method whenever i need to then it should be right and the data is returned in a string like this ['start', 'inch', '640', '480', '0', '0', '640', '480', '488', '290', '15', 'teset1', '336', '184', '37', 'eom']

Comment: @Edward the `'start'` and `'eom'` is omitted. If you need it, I'll leave it for you to correct. The `int()` stuff will need to be corrected as well if some of your data aren't numeric...